# How to enable perfect and full intellisense for specific functions in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

In the visual studio code, as soon as I type the `pr` ... it shows  me `printf` and soon as I hit `enter` it just writes `printf`  as a normal variable but it doesn't auto complete like `printf("")`.

Can you please help me to how to add this auto complete feature in visual studio code windows edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way, and this worked for me.
Try doing this:

Go to `File > Preferences > User Snippets`, type in (`c.json`)

There you can create your own snippets.  For example :

```
"printf": {
  "prefix": "print",
  "body": ["printf(\"$1\",$2);", "$3"],
  "description": "Printf statement" 
 },

"include": {
  "prefix": "include",
  "body": ["#include<$1>", "$2"],
  "description": "Include Statement"
 }
```

You will even find the instructions in the `c.json` file in the form of comments, follow them and customize the way you want, and you are set ready.

Thank You :)